# How can I query XPath matching an attribute from one tag against another attribute from another tag?

Tags: xpath

I'm scripting a web app that has labels for input fields. EG:

```
<label for="surname">Family Name:</label>...<input id="surname" ...></input>
```

I'd like to be able to write an XPath expression that takes the text "Family Name:" to match the label, then takes the "for" attribute from the label and uses that to find the associated input tag by matching its "id" tag.

I can make this "work" as follows:

```
//label[contains(.,"Family Name:")]/following::input[1]
```

However, for this web app I think it would be more reliable to match for/id. (EG: How can I be sure that in all possible layouts  the first input tag following the label is the one I want? And what happens if somewhere down the line this page is rendered using a right-to-left script?

My ultimate aim is to create a library function that we can use to write QA scripts in advance of web pages to test against, when all we have is a picture or document with an input field labelled "Family Name:" and no idea what id some programmer will ultimately assign to the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
//input[@id = //label[contains(., "Family Name:")]/@for]
```

As for your ultimate goal, you may want to take a look at the [XPath](https://github.com/jnicklas/xpath) gem for Ruby. Some of what you're doing may already be implemented there. (Specifically, check out the library's [HTML Helpers](https://github.com/jnicklas/xpath/blob/master/lib/xpath/html.rb))

Comment: After changing "==" to "=" it worked perfectly. I'm not working in Ruby right now, but I'll definitely check out the links you recommended. Thanks!

Comment: @user635712 K, I changed the `==` to `=` in my answer.